# MariaDB elegir motor de almacenamiento

Tags: mariadb

estuve leendo sobre los diferentes motores de almacenamiento soportado en Mysql de los mas conocidos parece que son InnoDB y MyISAM, pero con MariaDB parece que existen mas opciones, el tema es que no se muy bien cual usar, por lo que estoy recurriendo a vuestra experiencias y conocimiento para que me den una mano en esto, la Base de Datos que estoy usando se genera a partir de un sistema externo que recaba informacion de de un sistema SCADA, este Sistema esta escribiendo en la tabla "DATOS" todo el tiempo y genera gran cantidad de registros, tanto asi que pude constatar que en un mes genero aproximadamente 7 millones de registros, esos datos se usan para generar reportes mediante un programa externo escrito en C# y reportViewer la tabla "DATOS" almacena los valores de proceso en un solo campo llamado "valores" este campo guarda todos los registros que envia el SCADA, por lo que para mostrarlo en reportes es necesario convertir esa columna de datos en varias filas en funcion al codigo de cada dato.
este reporte se usa en promedio 3 a 5 veces al dia.
como podran ver si bien la aplicacion no tiene muchas consultas update o delete, guarda grandes cantidades de informacion y debe servir consultas medianamente complejas.

Trate de ser lo las claro posible, pero si hay alguna consulta, por favor comentenlo.

Saludos a todos.

Comment: qué tipo de datos piensas guardar?, podrías dar un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Soporta muchos motores de almacenamiento, pero cada uno tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, te aconsejo que te inicies por InnoDB, de todos modos te explico los más comunes para que tengas una idea:

- [MyISAM:](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) Fue el primero y por defecto para versiones anteriores de MySQL 5.5:
  No es transaccional, no soporta claves foraneas.
  Está optimizado para altas operaciones de lectura.
  Soporta solo bloqueo de tablas y no de registros, por eso es ineficiente para operaciones INSERT, UPDATE y DELETE de forma concurrente.
  No se aconseja como motor principal.
  No es seguro en caso de desastre.
- [InnoDB:](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB) Es el más extendido, más seguro, es completamente transaccional ACID, tiene practicamente el mismo rendimiento que MyISAM. MariaDB tiene la exclusidad de tener sobre este motor Columnas Virtuales.
- [TokoDB:](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/TokuDB) Tiene las mismas prestaciones que InnoDB, pero esta optimizado para altas operaciones de escritura.
- [CSV:](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/csv-overview/) Es lo más básico que hay, guarda el contenido en CSV, no tiene ninguna ventaja, se utiliza para guardar un log como el slow log o general log.
- FederatedX: Permite conectar una tabla con otra tabla alojada en otro servidor, no es optimo en rendimiento. Generalmente se utiliza para temas administrativos y se considera un agujero de seguridad.
- Blackhole: Como lo dice su nombre, es un agujero negro, todo lo que se graba desaparece. Suele usarse en los Slaves para temas administrativos.
- Aria: Es una versión mejorada de MyISAM para soportar únicamente fallas.
- XtraDB: Es una solución que implementa InnoDB con Galera para clusterizar.

Recomiendo ampliamente que empieces por InnoDB, y como segunda opción TokoDB. De todos modos, los requerimientos de Hardware como; Disco, CPU y Memoria RAM, son esenciales para un buen desempeño del servidor.

Comment: @root2 si necesitas más información y/o ejemplos, no dudes en preguntar.